# Conhecem alguma biblioteca para plotar gráficos em python além da Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, aprendizagem-de-máquina, k-means, clusterização

Gostaria de experimentar outros tipos de tabelas. Quero fazer uma classificação usando k-means e to procurando alguma com recurso de animação, sem que eu precise fazer essa animação na marra.

Answer (score 1):

**[Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/)** é uma plataforma Open Source. Tem excelentes *gráficos* e recursos de *[animações](https://plot.ly/python/#animations)*.

Segue link com um bom [tutorial em português](https://paulovasconcellos.com.br/como-criar-gr%C3%A1ficos-interativos-utilizando-plotly-e-python-3eb6eda57a2b) para criar gráficos interativos com Plotly.

Outras alternativas com excelentes *gráficos*:

- **[CairoPlot](https://linil.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/cairoplot-11/)** é uma biblioteca bastante simples e criada por brasileiros. Com ela é possível criar 6 tipos de gráficos, incluindo
  picha, donut, barras, linhas, etc. Os gráficos são bem elegantes.
- **[Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html)**, a concorrente mais próxima da Matplotlib.

Comment: A cairoplot tá ativa? Eu contribui alguma coisa pra ela, vários anos atrás - mas nunca mais mexi - ela não tinha muitas pretensões, como animações.

Comment: É -parece que não muito -  a última mexida nela faz tempo- tem um fork no github com um port para Python 3, mas o último commit foi há 4 anos - https://github.com/m-labs/cairoplot3 - talvez ela funcione ainda. Mas os gráficos ficam bonitos mais por conta de usar degradês nos elementos. Não tinha nenhum suporte a animação.

Comment: Encontrei códigos abertos de 2018 que utilizam a Cairoplot, por isso achei válido indicar.

Comment: que legal. Bom, mas a não ser que ela tenha sido refatorada depois do tempo que contribui, seriauma biblioteca difífil de incorparar animação - ela era meio amarrada.
A propria biblioteca "cairo", que é o backend da cairoplot, na verdade parece "parada",  mas está "concluída" - ela é "feature complete" para criar imagens e gráficos 2D, com vários backends diferentes - (saída pra tela, arquivos de imagem, etc...).